# Accessing a sharepoint stored file from Excel VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, vsto

Hi guys am new to VSTO add-ins and i am developing a project that should be able to take any excel file from a user specified location and modify it. It works fine until the user selects a file from sharepoint (This works by having a file opener so the user can browse to any location). I have looked through Microsoft documentation and online and can't even find a starting guide for how to do this.
Any suggestions on how i can get the file from sharepoint and modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the Excel object model can deal with local files. So, I'd suggest downloading files on the local hard drive before making any modifications.

For example, you may use the following code for downloading files from URLs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

class FileDownloader
{
    private readonly string _url;
    private readonly string _fullPathWhereToSave;
    private bool _result = false;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public FileDownloader(string url, string fullPathWhereToSave)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullPathWhereToSave)) throw new  ArgumentNullException("fullPathWhereToSave");

        this._url = url;
        this._fullPathWhereToSave = fullPathWhereToSave;
    }

    public bool StartDownload(int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_fullPathWhereToSave));

            if (File.Exists(_fullPathWhereToSave))
            {
                File.Delete(_fullPathWhereToSave);
            }
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var ur = new Uri(_url);
                // client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientDownloadProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClientDownloadCompleted;
                Console.WriteLine(@"Downloading file:");
                client.DownloadFileAsync(ur, _fullPathWhereToSave);
                _semaphore.Wait(timeout);
                return _result && File.Exists(_fullPathWhereToSave);
            }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Was not able to download file!");
            Console.Write(e);
            return false;
        }
       finally
       {
            this._semaphore.Dispose();
       }
    }

    private void WebClientDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("\r     -->    {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    private void WebClientDownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        _result = !args.Cancelled;
        if (!_result)
        {
            Console.Write(args.Error.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Download finished!");
        _semaphore.Release();
    }

    public static bool DownloadFile(string url, string fullPathWhereToSave, int timeoutInMilliSec)
    {
        return new FileDownloader(url, fullPathWhereToSave).StartDownload(timeoutInMilliSec);
    }
}
```

To use the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var success = FileDownloader.DownloadFile(fileUrl, fullPathWhereToSave, timeoutInMilliSec);
    Console.WriteLine("Done  - success: " + success);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this i will give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: Hi again sorry just had some time to look at this, would this prompt the user for their password/username or timeout ?